# C++ iostream >> operator behaves differently than get() unsigned char

Tags: c++, iostream, unsigned-char

I was working on a piece of code to do some compression, and I wrote a bitstream class.

My bitstream class kept track of the current bit we are reading and the current byte (unsigned char).

I noticed that reading the next unsigned character from the file was done differently if I used the >> operator vs get() method in the istream class.

I was just curious why I was getting different results?

ex:

```
this->m_inputFileStream.open(inputFile, std::ifstream::binary);   
unsigned char currentByte;
this->m_inputFileStream >> currentByte;
```

vs.

```
this->m_inputFileStream.open(inputFile, std::ifstream::binary);
unsigned char currentByte;
this->m_inputFileStream.get((char&)currentByte);
```

Additional Info:

To be specific the byte I was reading was 0x0A however when using >> it would read it as 0x6F

I'm not sure how they're even related ? (they're not the 2s complement of each other?)

The >> operator is also defined to work for unsigned char as well however (see [c++ istream class reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)

Comment: updated the question for some more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't parsing text, don't use `operator>>` or `operator<<`.  You'll get weird bugs that are hard to track down.  They are also resilient to unit tests, unless you know what to look for.  Reading a uint8 for instance will fail on 9 for instance.

edit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>

void test(char r) {
        std::cout << "testing " << r << std::endl;
        char t = '!';
        std::ostringstream os(std::ios::binary);
        os << r;
        if (!os.good()) std::cout << "os not good" << std::endl;
        std::istringstream is(os.str(), std::ios::binary);
        is >> t;
        if (!is.good()) std::cout << "is not good" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::hex << (uint16_t)r 
             << " vs " << std::hex << (uint16_t)t << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
        test('z');
        test('\n');
        return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
testing z
7a vs 7a
testing 

is not good
a vs 21
```

I suppose that would never have been evident a priori.

Comment: Your first sentence is OK. The rest is just balderdash in the general context of things. If you have some **specific** examples of what yo mean that would be constructive input otherwise I would consider it garbage and subject to a negative vote.

Comment: I see how it's resulting in an incorrect value but I'm unsure why still.

Comment: In terms of binary, 0x0A is the same as '\n'.  However, '\n' has a special meaning in a text formatted stream.  The shift operators are (as far as I understand it) a non-sense operation on a binary stream.  I don't understand why they do not fail *all the time*.  If you use read/write methods on the istream/ostream interfaces you won't have problems like this though.

Answer (score 2):

`operator>>` is for **formatted input**. It'll read `"23"` as an integer if you stream it into an `int`, and it'll eat whitespace between tokens. `get()` on the other hand is for **unformatted**, byte-wise input.

Comment: Correct answer. But OP is using `unsigned char` rather than int for formatted input. Can you explain how that changes things.

Comment: exactly. I was using unsigned char, so it should be giving me unsigned char?

Comment: You're still reading token by token, so you're bound to hit trouble when you get whitespaces, or anything that's not a single character surrounded by whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

C++'s formatted input (`operator >>`) treats `char` and `unsigned char` as a character, rather than an integer. This is a little annoying, but understandable.

You have to use `get`, which returns the next byte, instead.

However, if you open a file with the binary flag, you should not be using formatted I/O. You should be using `read`, `write` and related functions. Formatted I/O won't behave correctly, as it's intended to operate on text formats, not binary formats.

Comment: I would think treating a char as integer would be much more annoying. As I would expect symetric operation between << and >>. So if I output `0x49` I expect the input to read it as `0x49` even if the character it produces is 1. `std::cout << '1'; char x;std::cin >> x;` x better be the character '1'(0x49)